# How to use Texture Coordinates, Mapping and Gradient Texture nodes to generate a black and white mask?

Tags: texture-coordinates

Basically, I'm trying to understand how to generate a procedural mask. I'm trying to make an eye and I wanted a mask to make a difference between cornea and sclera, but the problem that I have is that I don't understand any of this as my eye ball just goes from solid white to solid black.

I can't seem to find or locate anything to make this mask for my eye.

How do people use these nodes to generate masks on objects? I really don't understand them.

[image]

Comment: maybe show a picture of what you want and what you've tried

Comment: I added a picture, all values give me black.

Comment: Hey :). Please add an image of what you want. For people who aren't well versed in eye anatomy (me).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could use *Gradient Texture* for that.

1. Add *Gradient Texture* set to *Linear* (default)
2. Use *ColorRamp* to control it.
3. Done

[image]